# Adding a UIButton to an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uibutton, xib

I am relatively new to coding in Swift and I'm updating an app that is currently in the app store. I am currently creating an array for contents in a cell for a tableView that I made in a xib file. Here is what it looks like:

```
`struct callData {
    let cell : Int?
    let hotlineName : String?
    let phoneNumber : String?
    let callBtn : UIButton?
    let iconImg : UIImage?

    init(cell:Int,hotlineName:String,phoneNumber:String, callBtn:UIButton, iconImg:UIImage) {
        self.cell = cell
        self.hotlineName = hotlineName
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        self.callBtn = callBtn
        self.iconImg = iconImg

    }
}

class _ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var arrayOfCallData = [callData(
            cell: 0,
            hotlineName:"",
            phoneNumber:"",
            callBtn:"",
            iconImg: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "smartphone")
        )]
```

`

I'm not sure how to insert a button (callBtn) into an array (arrayOfCallData) without it providing plenty of errors. The purpose of it is to call the number from within the string from the app but I'm not sure how to implement an action for the button to call. 
here is an example of the code for calling from within the app:

`let url = NSURL(string: "tel://8004424673")!
        UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL)`

I want to be able to incorporate this into the array (callBtn) so that I can create multiple buttons that can call different numbers.

Comment: I edited your code formatting the best I could. Indenting four spaces for code is the correct markdown. I then indented with the arrayOfCallData` as best I could - please correct if wrong. I'm finding it very hard (possibly syntactically wrong even) to make sense of the `callBtn` key - which is probably your issue. Maybe you can find the various errors by breaking the `let url` into two (maybe three) lines of code, *building* the value of that key.

Comment: Thank you! I accidentally deleted a comma between callBtn and iconImg.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You can't say `let` anything after `callBtn:` in an initializer. A initializer wants _objects_, not code. A phrase starting with `let` is not a button.

Comment: I agree with @matt. Your editted code looks much better (thanks for it), but obviously this is (1) not code that is both in the App Store with *something* for the `callBtn` key, (2) is missing all of the previous code you posted which may be the issue you are asking help on, and (3) ends up confusing the actual issue (at least to me). We are left with this *"I'm not sure how to insert a button (callBtn) into an array (arrayOfCallData) without it providing plenty of errors.". That's pretty basic, so I'm guessing there's more - and also guessing that your edit is part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your callData, save your phone number as callBtnAction and you can fetch it back in selector method.

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cellIdendifier: String = "CallDataCell"

    let cellData = arrayOfCallData[indexPath.row]

    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdendifier, for: indexPath)
    let button = UIButton.init()
    button.frame = CGRect.zero //Set your frame here
    button.setTitle(cellData.callBtnText, for: UIControlState.normal)
    button.tag = indexPath.row
    button.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("buttonClicked:")), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    cell.addSubview(button)
    return cell

}

func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    let selectedRow = sender.tag
    let callData = arrayOfCallData[selectedRow]
    let action = callData.callBtnAction
    print(action)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cells should own the views (e.g. buttons) and your data should be used to decorate those views. So if you remove the UI concerns from your data e.g. replacing the UIButton reference with a button title string, you can apply that data to the cell views in the `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, I should change `let callBtn: UIButton?` to a string and move the let statement to the `cellForRowAt`? I'm sorry, I am not completely grasping this.

Comment: Yes, try replacing `let callBtn: UIButton` with `let callBtnTitle: String`. Notice your UIViewController implements UITableViewDataSource, this means that your view controller will implement a `cellForRowAt` method where you can fill in each cell by applying your data to it. Your cell should already have a button in it defined in the xib. The general idea is that the xib file has all of the UIViews in it and your table and cells will all be created for you. You then apply your data to each cell e.g. cell.button.setTitle("StringFromYourData", for: .normal). Good luck!